# Differentiate this problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am not sure about my solution. Can anyone help in this regard? 
$$\frac d{dx}\sqrt{2\ln x}$$

Comment: where's your solution?

Comment: It will be my pleasure if you solve this.

Comment: @SanjedArmanBishal  Welcome to math.SE first of all!

Comment: Please take the time to reread your post & rework it: You do not propose a *solution*, so how can we understand your first sentence? The chosen *tag [ode]* does not fit with the contents of your post. Formulate a *concise question!* And you should be *more specific in the title*: Is it about differentiating the indicated function? Your post can be improved in many aspects, and it's up to *you perform an edit* (otherwise 4 days remain until the closure of the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $$(2\ln(x))^{1/2}$$ so we get by the power and chain rule
$$\frac{1}{2}(2\ln(x))^{-1/2}\times \frac{2}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the chain rule:

$$\frac{df(u)}{dx} =\frac{df}{du} *\frac{du}{dx}$$

with $$f = \sqrt u$$ and $$u= \ln(x^2)$$

this gives you

$$\frac{d}{du}(\sqrt{u})*\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(x^2))$$

this will give you, after solving the derivatives and back substituting:

$$\frac{1}{2* \sqrt{\ln(x^2)}} * \frac{2}{x}$$, which gives you

$$ =\frac{1}{x* \sqrt{\ln(x^2)}}$$

Comment: Thank you sir. It matches with my answer. Now im pretty sure.